# "please wait" during long operation in Qt?

Tags: qt, wait, progress

I need to do an operation after a user clicking a button, and that may take some time. How can I display a "busy" or "please wait" icon/message (like a spinning circle etc) and prevent a user from clicking the button again (or some other buttons) during the time? Thanks.

Comment: You can display an image of what you want.

Comment: gif animation add in qdialog and show))

Comment: How is displaying an image stops user clicking a button? Do I still have to add control to each button?

Comment: @YeP updated my answer. Look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your QApplication object's static function `setOverrideCursor(const QCursor &cursor)`

Set the wait cursor, to make the application "busy", as shown below.

```
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::WaitCursor));
```

And restore using below function, when you feel the work is done

```
QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
```

some documentation help:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#setOverrideCursor

Now to disable the window, override the event filter function of your window class.

declare a global variable, that says "busy" or "notbusy". ex: `_isBusy`.

In the event filter do something as shown below.

`eventfilter` is a virtual function of `QObject`.

So you can override in your window class as shown below.

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
     if (_isBusy) //your global variable to check "busy or "notbusy"
     {
         //Just bypass key and mouse events
          switch(event->type())
          {
             case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
             case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
             case QEvent::KeyPress:
             case QEvent::KeyRelease:
             return true;
          }
     }
}
```

***Note: "MainWindow" in the above function declaration is your class name. Also in the switch statement, I limited the count to only 4 events, add as many events you want.***

Comment: This is cool, however I found that this just change how the cursor look, and I can still click things even with cursor show as "busy"... any idea? Thanks.

Comment: The cursor code just displays the cursor. If you want to disable the window during that time, override "eventfilter" in your window class and bypass major "key" and "mouse" events.

Comment: Updated the answer, saying how to override the event filter for busy case. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this but doesn't look like it bypass the mouse click... the click to a button is still taken while isBusy is set although the operation of such button only happen after the original process is completed.

Comment: Could you please post "eventfilter" code in your question?

Comment: I copy exactly your code. I think the problem I have is that the operation I launched is not in a separate thread. I'm supposed to put long running operation to a separate thread, is that right?

Comment: You forgot `QCoreApplication::instance()->installEventFilter(this);`